# How to make a column with an adaptive width?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I have two questions in creating the following table:

1) How to make the first sub-column (with title No.) adaptive in width? Now it has the same width with the second sub-column, but I'd like to make the No. column narrower.

2) How to vertically center the Employee column title "Employee"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
{ *2{>{\centering}m{2cm}| }
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|
 *2{>{\centering}m{1.6cm}| }
 >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Location} & Production &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ratio in Year} & Employees & Profit \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-1}\cline{4-1}\cline{5-1}
 No. & coordinates& (lb.) & 1983 & 1984 && \$ \\ \hline
1 & -2 36 27 & 28000 & 0.35 & 0.31 & 17 & 542800\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the adaptive width just split the definition of the first two columns, keeping the `m{2cm}` column for the second and introducing a `c` column for the first. `c`, `l`, and `r` columns all take the natural width of text as width.

For the vertical centering you can use the `\multirow{<rows>}{<width>}{<content>}` command from the `multirow` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    c|                              %first column
    >{\centering}m{2cm}|            
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
    |*2{>{\centering}m{1.6cm}| }
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}
}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Location} & Production &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ratio in Year} & \multirow{2}{*}{Employees} & Profit \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{2-1}\cline{4-1}\cline{5-1}
 No. & coordinates& (lb.) & 1983 & 1984 && \$ \\ \hline
1 & -2 36 27 & 28000 & 0.35 & 0.31 & 17 & 542800\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the kind help. BTW, how do you upload the generated jpg file?

Comment: @bluepole there is a landscape-like squared icon in the edit box toolbar. Just click on that and select the .jpg/png/gif/whatever from your hard disk